# Python: Dictionary of matrices saves same value to every key from file

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, matrix, matplotlib

I want to make a function which takes a data file and a dictionary where every value is a (???,12)matrix of nympy nan's, and return the dictionary with values from the data file. not all the data from the file is supposed to go into the dictionary.

I've managed to get all the correct data and put it into the first matrix, the thing is every matrix is a copy of the first! I don't understand why this is since I'm taking all the data points line by line.

```
def read_temperature_dict(datfile, tempdictionary):
    ''''something'''
    dat = open(datfile)
    for key in tempdictionary:
        for line in dat.readlines():
            ID = line[:11]
            lineyear = line[11:15]
            lineyear = int(lineyear)
            try:
                indexlineyear = year_to_index(lineyear)
            except:
                continue
            jan = line[19:24]
            feb = line[27:32]
            mar = line[35:40]
            apr = line[43:48]
            may = line[51:56]
            jun = line[59:64]
            jul = line[67:72]
            aug = line[75:80]
            sep = line[83:88]
            oct = line[91:96]
            nov = line[99:104]
            dec = line[107:112]
            months = [jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec]
            count = 0
            for temp in months:
                newtemp = float(temp)
                if count <= 12:
                    if newtemp == -9999:
                        count += 1
                        continue
                    else:
                        newtemp = newtemp / 100.0
                        tempdictionary[ID][indexlineyear, count] = newtemp
                        count += 1
    dat.close()
    return tempdictionary
```

So, if I write:

```
mydicttwo = read_temperature_dict('ghcnm.tavg.v3.3.0.20151011.qca_test.dat', mydict)  
for key in mydicttwo:  
    print key, mydicttwo[key]
```

The result is two identical keys:

```
20558362000 [[ 2.56 4.86 8.46 ..., 18.46 12.36 7.16] [ 5.26 1.76 8.26 ..., 18.66 11.26 5.96] [ 6.66 5.66 11.06 ..., 18.36 14.16 7.46] ..., [ 2.2 2. 6.3 ..., 17.6 9.9 5.6 ] [ 2.9 3.1 6.3 ..., 15.8 11.2 4.2 ] [ 3.4 4.1 6.3 ..., nan nan nan]]  
21047600000 [[ 2.56 4.86 8.46 ..., 18.46 12.36 7.16] [ 5.26 1.76 8.26 ..., 18.66 11.26 5.96] [ 6.66 5.66 11.06 ..., 18.36 14.16 7.46] ..., [ 2.2 2. 6.3 ..., 17.6 9.9 5.6 ] [ 2.9 3.1 6.3 ..., 15.8 11.2 4.2 ] [ 3.4 4.1 6.3 ..., nan nan nan]]
```

Comment: You should put your code in a code block, so that the indentations will be preserved and someone could see what is wrong with it.

Comment: sorry this is my firs time posting how do i do that?